# What is the probability that it was the two-headed coin?

Tags: probability

There are four coins in a box. One is a two-headed coin, two are fair coins, and the third is a biased coin that comes up tails 65 percent of the time. When one of the four coins is selected at random and flipped, it shows heads.

Please help me to solve it. Advance thanks

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Can you please show the work you have so far.

Comment: This should be a straightforward application of [Total Probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability) and [Bayes' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem).  Can you at least find the probability that if you were to pick a coin at random and flip it that it does show heads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability you're asking for is the conditional probability of having thrown the two-headed coin after knowing the result is heads. It's value can be calculated by the following expression (calling $X$ the event of throwing the two headed coin, and $H$ the event of getting heads after the throw):
$$P[X|H]=\frac{P[X\cap H]}{P[H]},$$
so we calculate $P[H]$, which clearly is:
$$P[H]=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{2}+\frac{35}{100}\cdot\frac{1}{4}=\frac{47}{80}.$$
We already know that $P[X\cap H]=P[X]=\frac{1}{4}$ because it will always give you heads as result and the coins are selected with equal chance. So the final probability is:
$$P[X|H]=\frac{P[X\cap H]}{P[H]}=\frac{\frac{1}{4}}{\frac{47}{80}}=\boxed{\frac{20}{47}}$$

Comment: Thank you so much sir.

Comment: @TanvirAhmedHowlader your welcome! Tell me if there's anything that needs more explanation.

Comment: Is P[H]=1/4+1/4⋅1/2+1/4⋅1/2+35/100⋅1/2=27/40? and is 35 from 65?.

Comment: @TanvirAhmedHowlader Sorry that's a writing mistake, I'll edit it now. Thanks for pointing it.

Comment: Dear sir please explain why 35% instead of 65%?Thanks

Comment: Because your question said that coin had a 65% chance of throwing **tails**, so the chances of it throwing heads is 100-65=35%.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118999/discussion-between-tanvir-ahmed-howlader-and-alejandro-bergasa-alonso).